# Make nested for each Using Explode

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, explode

i need to get array value for key2  so instead of

```
 key2: "value2-bonusValue"
```

i need to get it like this

```
 key2: {
        "value2",
        "bonusValue"
        }
```

second if i removed : from one of arrays i get Undefined offset: 1 i need to be able to get array without key and key with multikeyes

```
  $my_string = "key0:value0,key1:value1,key2:value2-bonusValue";

        $convert_to_array = explode(',', $my_string);
        foreach($convert_to_array as $_array){
              $temp = explode(":", $_array);
              $arrays[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
        }
        return $arrays;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing just one set, the splitting of the sub elements.  In this code it splits the value by `-`, but if there is only 1 element then it sets it back to being the first element, otherwise it adds the sub array in...

```
$convert_to_array = explode(',', $my_string);
foreach($convert_to_array as $_array){
    $temp = explode(":", $_array);
    $sub = explode("-", $temp[1]);
    if ( count($sub) == 1 )    {
        $sub = $sub[0];
    }
    $arrays[$temp[0]] = $sub;
}
print_r( $arrays );
```

which gives...

```
Array
(
    [key0] => value0
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value2
            [1] => bonusValue
        )

)
```

For a missing `:` you can check the number of elements in `$temp`...

```
$convert_to_array = explode(',', $my_string);
foreach($convert_to_array as $_array){
    $temp = explode(":", $_array);
    if ( count($temp) == 2 )    {
        $sub = explode("-", $temp[1]);
        if ( count($sub) == 1 )    {
            $sub = $sub[0];
        }
        $arrays[$temp[0]] = $sub;
    }
}
```

Not sure what you want to do with the value though.

Comment: if i deleted : i get error Undefined offset: 1 can i fix that

Comment: I've added some more code which should check for that.

Comment: Not sure how you want to add it - you could just do `$arrays[] = $temp;` - put it in a `else` for the checking `count($temp) == 2`